# Whats the url for Magento2.0 SOAP V2

Tags: magento2, soap-api-v2

I'm trying to figure out how to get to V2 soap in magento2.0  I'm not having any luck finding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only URL Soap on Magento 2 is

```
http://<magento_host>/soap/<store_code>?wsdl&services=<serviceName1,serviceName2,..
```

The value of store_code can be one of the following:

- default
- assigned store code
- all

Example with default:

```
http://<magento_host>/soap/default?wsdl_list=1
```